# Windows 7, activating MAK or KSM key at home, is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

someone sold me a windows 7 enterprise and gave me MAK and KSM key. So I wonder if I can actually activate it at home and which key to choose?

what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the MAK key and yes, you could activate it from home.